# GIF splash screen gets stuck (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, gif, splash-screen, preloader

I have created splash screen as a Preloader that displays animated GIF image. Problem is that GIF gets stuck, because it is executed on the same JavaFX thread which is used start up the main Stage.

Is there any way to display GIF splash screen smoothly while JavaFX thread is starting up the main Stage?

Previously I used VM arguments to display GIF splash screen, but it lacks flexibility to resize for different screen resolutions, add additional loading/progress information etc.

Launcher:

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LauncherImpl.launchApplication(MainApp.class, SplashPreloader.class, args);
    }

}
```

Preloader (splash screen):

```
public class SplashPreloader extends Preloader {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage splashScreen) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        double width = 500;
        double height = 355;
        File file = new File("splash.gif");
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        ImageView splashGif = new ImageView(image);
        splashGif.setFitWidth(width);
        splashGif.setFitHeight(height);
        root.setCenter(splashGif);
        splashScreen.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height);
        splashScreen.setScene(scene);
        splashScreen.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: are you able to resolve this?

Comment: No I haven't, at least not this way. Currently I have solved this problem by simultaniously launching splash-screen as a Swing JFrame and main window as JavaFX application. And after start() of main application is finished, then I close JFrame (splash screen).